# Populate the array of arrays data with Angular Table?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to populate the Angular Table with the array of arrays data format. I have written the code but it does not work. please suggest the solution.

This is the data, that I need to populate

```
let activities = [
    ['Work', 9],
    ['Eat', 1],
    ['Commute', 2],
    ['Play Game', 1],
    ['Sleep', 7]
];
```

This is the code that I tried

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let data of activities ">
        <tr>
          <td>{{data}}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: <td>{{data[0]}}</td>
<td>{{data[1]}}</td>

Comment: What's "Angular Table"? Is it an external package, if so, please provide a link so that we can see its documentation.

Comment: <ng-container *ngFor="let data of activities ">
        <tr *ngFor="let d  of data">
          <td>{{d}}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let data of activities ">
      <tr>
        <td>{{data[0]}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>{{data[1]}}</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```